# I want know the rank in a Django queryset

Tags: mysql, django

I have a product list model and would like to know the ranking of a specific price of this model.

```
sorted_product_list = Product.objects.all().order_by('-price')
my_product = {'id': 10, 'price': 20000}
```

django has `RowNum` class but it is not support for mysql
i have only one idea that use `enumerate`

```
for rank, element in enumerate(sorted_product_list):
    if element.id == my_product.id:
        my_product_rank = rank
```

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Does the `'price'` key has the *real* price? If so, we can use binary search.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 5):

We can obtain the *rank* by `Count`ing the number of `Product`s with a *higher* `price` (so the ones that would have come first), so:

```
rank = Product.objects.filter(price__gt=myproduct['price']).count()
```

Or in case we do not know the price in advance, we can first fetch the price:

```
actual_price = Product.objects.values_list('price', flat=True).get(id=myproduct['id'])
rank = Product.objects.filter(price__gt=actual_price).count()
```

So instead of "generating" a table, we can filter the number of rows above that row, and count it.

Note that in case *multiple* `Product`s have the *same* price, we will take as rank the smallest rank among those `Product`s. So if there are four products with prices $ 200, $ 100, $100, and $ 50, then both `Product`s with price $ 100 will have rank `1`. The `Product` that costs $ 50 will have rank `3`. In some sense that is logical, since there is no "internal rank" among those products: the database has the freedom to return these products in any way it wants.

Given there is an index on the `price` column (and it is a *binary tree*), this should work quite fast. The query will thus *not* fetch elements from the database.

In case the internal rank *is* important, we can use an approach where we first determine the "*external* rank", and then iterate through `Product`s with the same price to determine the "*internal* rank", but note that this does not make much sense, since between two queries, it is possible that this "internal order" will change:

```
# rank that also takes into account *equal* prices, but *unstable*
actual_price = Product.objects.values_list('price', flat=True).get(id=myproduct['id'])
rank = Product.objects.filter(price__gt=actual_price).count()
for p in Product.objects.filter(price=actual_price):
    if p.id != myproduct['id']:
        rank += 1
    else:
        break
```

we thus keep incrementing while we have not found the product, in case we have, we stop iterating, and have obtained the rank.